# How can I Redirect to a Switch Route in the same class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom

My `App.js` contains all of my react-router routes, like so:

```
<div>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/a" component={A} />
        <Route path="/b" component={B} />
        <Route path="/c" child={<C UID={UID} />} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

within my `App.js`  I check to see if my DB has a user with the specified UID grabbed from localStorage. If it does not, I would like to redirect to my c route.

I have tried using `window.location.assign("/c")` and `<Redirect to="/c" />`, but both have their problems.

i.e.
trying window.location.assign(), which just then gets called endlessly in an infinite loop.

```
function App(){
    const [UID, setUID] = useState(localStorage.getItem("UID");

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (UID) { 
            checkUserExists(UID)
               .then((exists) => {
                   if (!exists){
                       window.location.assign("/c");
                   }
                });
        }
    }, [])
    
    return (
      #first code snippet in post
    )
}
```

trying with Redirect, which just loads an empty page. I assume because it returns just the Redirect instead of all of my routes.

```
function App(){
    const [UID, setUID] = useState(localStorage.getItem("UID");
    const [UserExists, setUserExists] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (UID) {
            checkUserExists(UID)
               .then((exists) => {
                   if (!exists){
                       setUserExists(false);
                   }
                });
        }
    }, [])

   if (!UserExists){
       return <Redirect to="/c" />
   return (
      #first code snippet in post
   )
}
```

Does anybody know what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I changed the `Switch` in `App.js` return, and kept the UID and userExists (which I set accordingly) states.

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/">
       {userExists ? <HomePage /> : <Redirect to="/c" />}
   </Route>
   <Route path="/a" component={A} />
   <Route path="/b" component={B} />
   <Route path="/c" child={<C UID={UID} />} />
</Switch>
```